# How to use UIPanGestureRecognizer for moving multiple controls in the screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uipangesturerecognizer

How do I use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for moving multiple controls in the screen and how to identify which control in currently moving.

Example:

I'm using `UITextField`, `UIButton` and `UIImageView` in a view. I'm able to move multiple controls by using the different instantiate for each control but the method for panning is same method.

Please help me find out which control currently I'm panning in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

1)Here is how you can set the pag gesture

```
- (void)setupGestures
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(movePanel:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}
```

2)This method gets called whenever the view moves

```
  -(void)movePanel:(id)sender
    {

    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    //here are different states from which you can change view

        if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {


        }

        if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    // Are you more than halfway? If so, show the panel when done dragging by setting this value to YES (1).
    // Here you can change the position of the component depending on translation point 
   // translatedPoint.x & translatedPoint.y  keep on changing as you move view over screen


        }
    }
```

3)For checking which view is moving you can check the view by tag & identify the view from that tag & change the frame

Comment: im strucking in dragging multiple controls so gave suggestion codes on that perspective. and how the we know which control is dragging from the multiple controls on the screen

Comment: as I have mentioned you could check from tag